# Hide the Breadcrumb Links in Sharepoint

Tags: 2007, navigation

KPI Dashboards > KPI > Summary

The navigation Bar looks like this. Sorry i couldnt post the image since im new to this site and dont have enough rep :(.

So KPI Dashboards is the name of the site, KPI is a report library in It and Summary is a dashboard page in that report library. So upon navigating to Sumamry Page , this treeview navigation is visible above the summary page title. Using Out of box how can i hide this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press F12 in your browser, inspect the elements containing it and give the element `Display:none;` in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

With Ziga's help i was able to identify the Solution :

1)Added a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) to my page

2)Open Source Editor and enter following within style tags :

td.ms-titlearea 
{
 display:none; 
}

3) Make CEWP Hidden under Appearance before saving

Answer (score 0):

This was one of the first things I started to use jQuery for a few years back.  In my case I didn't want to remove all of the breadcrumb elements, but only the redundant ones.  In this case maybe just the KPI part.  In any case, jQuery has some advanced selectors that can be applied allowing you to do some very advanced showing/hiding on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the info Mike. jQuery would help alongside out of box right ? . I prefer coding myself but clients want it to be  an entirely out of box solution.

Comment: you would need to reference the jquery library, the rest is done through client code.  The jquery library is available from places like google apis already hosted online which would mean you wouldn't have to upload anything to the server.

Comment: Brilliant , then i can just wrap my code in a cewp with references to online hosted libs. thanks